# Convert Java Object to JSON using Groovy JsonBuilder

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am trying to convert Java Object to JSON using Groovy JsonBuilder

**Java POJO Class**

```
public class Employee {

    String name;

    int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Groovy Script**

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.name="Vinod"
employee.age=24

println new JsonBuilder( employee ).toPrettyString()
```

**Output**

```
{

}
```

I am not sure if I am using JsonBuilder incorrectly. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a Java POJO, you need to add the *getters* for the two properties you have, i.e., `public String getName()` and `public String getAge()`.

The JsonBuilder leverages [`DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#getProperties(java.lang.Object)) to get object properties. If you don't add the aforementioned getters, it does not find any properties and therefore the resulting JSON is empty.

So that:

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Employee{name=%s, age=%d}", name, age);
    }
}
```

If you use a POGO instead (Plain Old Groovy Object), *getters* are added by default for each property, so it works out of the box: